# What makes matrices unique?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume we have a matrix $H$ that is diagonizable. If we perform spectral decomposition on $H$ forming a new matrix $H'$  whose columns are the eigenbases of $H$, can we say that $H' =H$?

In other words, if two matrices share the same basis, eigenvalues, eigenvectors, and transformation operations, can we conclude they are the same matrix?

Comment: Do you know the principle "diagonalization"?

Answer (score 0):

$$H=PDP^{-1}$$ where $D$ is formed from the Eigenvalues and $P$ from the Eigenvectors. Unless you swap these elements, the matrix is uniquely defined.

Comment: What if P was the identity matrix I, what does this say about H?

Comment: Think: if $P$ is $\mathbb{I}$, then what is $P^{-1}$? Do the (easy) computation $\mathbb{I}DP^{-1}$.

Comment: @DiaaEldinMalek: this seems obvious.